# How to disable account creation in firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've a project in which I used to authenticate the users with `firebase-auth`.In my project users can not create their accounts on their own.Only admin have the privilege to add the user accounts.

In order to use `onAuthStateChanged()` function I must use `firebase-auth` in my page.But the issue is because of using `firebase-auth` on client side one can esaily create accounts by running `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function on the console without having the admin privilege.

Now how can I restrict the people from using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function on client side?

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can stop clients apps from creating accounts is to disable all authentication providers for your project in the Firebase console.  You could write an [auth onCreate Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) that attempts to figure out if a new account was created by client or admin code if you want to try to delete it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

In 2022 with Firebase Auth with Identity Platform and blocking functions, we can accomplish that the following way:

Create an HTTP function that receives email, password and displayName, and creates user using firebase-admin:

```html
import { https } from 'firebase-functions';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase-admin/auth';
import cors from 'cors';

const auth = getAuth();

// Register an HTTP function with the Functions Framework
export const signupUser = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const options = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
  };
  cors(options)(req, res, () => {
    console.log('all good');
    auth
    .createUser({
      email: 'example@email.com',
      emailVerified: false,
      password: 'secretPassword',
      displayName: 'John Doe',
      disabled: false,
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
      console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
    });
  
    // Send an HTTP response
    res.send('OK');
  });
});
```

**Modify response and origin in CORS as you need.**

Now create a blocking beforeCreate function and check for user's display name, if there is no display name, throw an error:

```html
import { auth } from "firebase-functions";
import { initializeApp, applicationDefault } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase-admin/auth';
import postmark from 'postmark';

const app = initializeApp({
  credential: applicationDefault(),
  projectId: 'your_project_id',
});

const tnc = getAuth(app);

export const signUp = auth
    .user().beforeCreate((user, context) => {
      if (!user.displayName) {
        throw new auth.HttpsError('permission-denied');
      }
});
```

**This will work because there is no way to include "display name" when signing up via client side**

So you, in short, point is to create a Cloud Function that will register users and make sure to add the check to beforeCreate for something that you know is only possible to do on server-side via firebase-admin sdk.

**EDIT: CORRECTION**

Just found out you can now disable client side signup from Firebase Console if you have Auth + Identity Platform

Comment: How to disable client side signup from Firebase Console? Using blocking function? Any examples?

Comment: @Jim You just do it via Firebase Console, no coding needed. Just go on Authentication > Settings > User actions (or something like that, depending on your language). You just uncheck the checkbox and it will be impossible for anyone to sign up via client side. Then all you need is to create a Cloud Function or set up your own API using firebase-admin to handle the sign ups.

Comment: Does disabling client side signup from Firebase Console, disable all type of signup, with email and password, google, facebook? I am asking this because I need to block signup with email and password on client side and only allow signup with google.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a claim once the user is added, via a cloud function, which requires authorization, so that if the user doesn't have that claim he can't use the app or can't login.